# Python3 cannot receive image correctly

Tags: python-3.x, tcp

i have a problem with python3 sockets. I made a function that receives a list of bytes, than creates an image with the bytes that are in the list. I got a specific task to encrypt the bytes using a symmetric key algorithm but the problem is another. After i had received all the data, if i put a `break` in the client and in the server loop, the image will be received without any problems. But if i want to send another message to the server, after sending to it the image, that the problem occurs. The function seems to stop receiving. I noticed that, after sending the image bytes to the other side, if the loop does not stop, the function that has to receive the image cannot receive any byte. So it blocks in the first `self.connection.recv(4096)` and it does not receive anything. Keep in mind that I'm a beginner a that's just a random task. Yup, the server and the client are inverted, so the server asks the client for informations (the client has to send the image to the server).

```
server.py

def send_file(self, file_path):
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        bytes = []
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                data = base64.b64encode(f.read(1024))
                ciphertext = self.encryption.encrypt(data.decode("utf-8"))
                bytes.append(ciphertext)
                if not data:
                   break
            f.close()
        data = pickle.dumps(bytes)
        self.socket.send(data)
        print("sent")

client.py

def download_file(self, file_name, file_extension):
    bytes_received = []
    while True:
        data = self.connection.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            break
        bytes_received.append(data)
        print(bytes_received)
    try:
        data_arr = pickle.loads(b"".join(bytes_received))
    except EOFError:
        print("[-] the file does not exists")
        return
    print(data_arr)
    with open(file_path + file_name + "." + file_extension, 'wb') as f:
        for byte in data_arr:
            decrypted_bytes = base64.b64decode(self.encryption.decrypt(byte))
            f.write(decrypted_byte)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Ops I forgot something. In the client.py file, after print(data_arr), i obviously create the file (in that case, an image)         

`with open(file_path + file_name + "." + file_extension, 'wb') as f:
    for byte in data_arr:
        decrypted_byte = base64.b64decode(self.encryption_aes.decrypt(byte))
        f.write(decrypted_byte)
    f.close()`

Comment: Could you edit that comment back into the code you provided?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, i did it now

Comment: Just a side note, when you open a file as a context manager (eg `with open(path) as f: ...`) you don't need to explicitly call `f.close`, the context manager is there to do that for you

Comment: okay, thanks for the note, but the problem remains because i tried even without the file creation code

Comment: I have several questions about your code like why are you decoding a base64 string, where does `encrypted_msg` comes from in `server.py` and why are you pickling a list of whatever `encrypt` returns in server and loading an string in `client.py`. Also I'm not really sure base64 encoding is intended for chunks of binary data rather than the whole thing.

Comment: `encrypted_msg` is `ciphertext`, my bad. `encrypt` is a function of a class that has been given to us to accomplish the task. The problem is not the encryption or the file, the problem is that, when i send the list, i want to send another input after that and, in that case, the first `self.connection.recv(4096)` won't receive anything. It receives the data only if I close the server after `self.socket.send(data)`